# Highlight the "Ask" link for mobile site

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web, new-users

I usually ask questions via the desktop site. Today, I had a burning question that I wanted to ask via my phone. It took me quite some time to figure out how, because the "Ask" link is "hidden in plain sight".

[image: Where is the Ask button... Oh, there it is.]

I propose to highlight the Ask button a bit, say by making it **Strong** and/or with a different color and/or within a contrasting box, so people that are not familiar with the mobile interface can quickly see where they're supposed to tap.

**Edit:** Another alternative is to implement the ubiquitous "floating circular button with plus sign at lower-right corner", but I figure just highlighting the "Ask" link requires less effort.

**Edit 2:** To all commenters helpfully telling *me* to activate the "responsive" version: Your comment will NOT help a newcomer puzzled on how to ask questions. They will visit the mobile site, hopefully register, and likely spend an inordinate time trying to find out how to ask a question, before possibly giving up and ask the question elsewhere, like on Reddit or Quora.

Comment: You can click the "Full site" link to enable the responsive version of the site (basically the same version used for desktop).

Comment: @KodosJohnson that still doesn't solve the problem of "people that are not familiar with the mobile interface" will not know what to do.

Comment: The mobile interface is going to be retired and the responsive theme made the default. So I'm not sure if SE would invest the time to make any changes to the mobile theme.

Comment: @Rubén if I, who happens to be quite experienced with Stack Exchange, couldn't figure that out on my own, do you think newcomers can figure that out? That's the main problem I'm trying to raise here, NOT just how to solve my own problem.

Comment: @pepoluan it's same issue as the apps: people using outdated software, so problems are expected. SE developers said more than once why won't make any further changes to the mobile design, since it's going to be replaced. Maybe it will take 10 more years, but their decision is final. They are still fixing bugs, but things which are just "nice to have" have very small chance of being done.

Comment: @pepoluan: if you are focusing your post on them I suggest you to create a new account to try the newcomers experience.